# Using prepositions with 'student'

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Recently, I asked a question on stack exchange music, and I was wondering wether I should us the word `for`,`to` or `of`. For example,

```
    I am a student to drums.
    I am a student of drums.
    I am a student for drums.
```

Which one of those is correct? Should I use another sentence structure? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Of your examples,

> I am a student of drums.

is closest to meaning that you are learning to play the drums.

You could say:

> I am a student of English.

because English is what you are studying.

But you are not literally studying the drums themselves (unless you want  to make them), you are studying how to play them.

So it might be more natural to say:

> I am studying (how) to play the drums.

Comment: Upvoted this good answer.  An anthropologist might be a "student of drums" (and be no drummer).

Answer (score 0):

> You can be a *student **for** a day* 
>   You can take a *student **to** lunch*, **and** 
>  You can be *student **of** some course/college/school.*

That said, the last one in your question seems to be the proper option. However, I'm not sure whether or not 'drum' can be used as a subject of study. Is it jargon used in music industry?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you are studying how to play drums then all of your examples are not recommended.

You may say *"I am a student of the Drum and blah blah blah course..."*
or *"I am enrolled in a drum lesson/course..."*